# Curly braces when calling a function from html in vue js

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, state, curly-braces

when calling function, for example on click it doesn't matter if I write curly braces or not. It works in both scenarios. But I made a function, which fires custom event from a child. then I await it in a parent component and fire my function (which is in parent),  to update state. I noticed when I write curly braces on that function, vue returns an error. why is that happening? (I'm new to vue js :) ).

function in a child component, which is invoked on click:

```
  toggleFavorite: function () {
          this.$emit("toggle-favorite", this.id);
        }
```

A child component rendered inside a parent

```
<friend-contact
      v-for="friend in friends"
      :data="friend"
      :key="friend.id"
      @toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite"> // if i write 'toggleFavorite()' here, I am 
                                         // geting an error
                                         
    </friend-contact>
```

A function which is fired on custom event

```
 toggleFavorite: function (id) {
      let friendToUpdate = this.friends.find((el) => el.id === id);
      friendToUpdate.favorite = !friendToUpdate.favorite;
    }
```

Comment: If you do `@toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite()"` you gonna invoke the function with a different signature that's not defined in your script

Answer (score 0):

An event doesn't matter, what matters here is whether a parameter is used in event handler or not.

`@toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite"` results in `toggleFavorite` being used as event handler.

`@toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite()"` results in `toggleFavorite()` expression being evaluated on event, with `id` parameter being `undefined`.

There is `$event` magic value that represents event parameter in event handler. In order to match the first syntax, it should be `@toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite($event)"`.